# Override foundation.css with my custom css problems

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I just started using Foundation 6.
I am using the simple archive with css files and js files.

I am trying to override the default font-family with mine, but foundation css style override my css. What am i doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: josefin;
    src: url('../fonts/josefin/JosefinSans-Regular.ttf');
}
body{
   font-family: 'josefin';
}
.main-header{
    background-color: #D72B3F;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
        <head>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/foundation-6/css/foundation.css">            
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css">                        
  </head>
        <body>
            <header>
                <div class='main-header expanded row'>
                    <div class='small-12 columns'>
                        <h1>Title</h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </header>

            <footer>
                <div class='row'>
                    <div class='small-12 colums'>
                        <h1>Footer</h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </footer>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>                    
        <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/foundation-6/js/foundation.min.js"></script>
  </body>
 </html>
```

Thanks.

Edit1 : I tried !important and it doesn't work.

Edit2 : I don't think it's about my css syntax in itself wrong, because when i desactivate the font entry of foundation.css in firebug i can display the font define in my custom css.

Comment: try adding (!important) at the end of the css you want to change eg (font-family: 'josefin' !important)  -- https://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/

Comment: Hello, i already tried !important ( i should mention it ) and it doesnt work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i fixed my issue, i feel sto stupid :)

I was testing the font on my  balise, and foundation.css have a specific rule for  elements.

So i had to override  in css.

```
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6{font-family: 'josefin';}
```

Here we go, thanks for help!